# Inverse of binary entropy function for $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

I'm trying to find the inverse of $H_2(x) = -x \log_2 x - (1-x) \log_2 (1-x)$<sup>[1]</sup> subject to $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{2}$. This is for a computation, so an approximation is good enough.

My approach was to take the Taylor series at $x=\frac{1}{4}$, cut it off as a quadratic, then find the inverse of that. That yields

$$H_2^{-1}(x) \approx -\frac{1}{16} \, \sqrt{-96 \, x \log\left(2\right) + 9 \, \log\left(3\right)^{2} - 72 \, \log\left(3\right) + 96 \, \log\left(4\right)} + \frac{3}{16} \, \log\left(3\right) + \frac{1}{4}$$

Unfortunately, that's a pretty bad approximation and it's complex at $H_2^{-1}(1)$. What other approaches can I take?

<sup>[1] I originally forgot to write the base 2 subscript (I added that in a later edit)</sup>

Answer (score 9):

A rather coarse approximation of $H_2(x)$ on the said interval is $4 \log(2) x(1-x)$. Hence a crude approximation for the inverse is:
$$
    H_2^{-1}(y) \approx \frac{1}{2} \left(1- \sqrt{1-\frac{y}{\log(2)}}\right) = \frac12\frac{y}{\log(2) + \sqrt{\log(2)\left(\log(2)-y\right)}}
$$
This initial approximation should be refined with Newton-Raphson method.

Comment: Thanks! How did you come up with $H_2(x) \approx 4 \log(2) x (1-x)$?

Comment: The entropy is symmetric function of $x$, suggesting to approximate it by a polynomial in $x(1-x)$.

Comment: @Red I meant symmetric around $x=1/2$.

Comment: +1. A slightly better approximation would be to choose $a$ such that $$\int_0^1 \left(H_2(x) - ax(1-x) \right)^2 dx$$ is minimized. This gives us $a= \dfrac{35}{12} \approx 2.91667$ as opposed to $a = 4 \log(2) \approx 2.7726$. Sasha's $4 \log 2$ ensures that the approximation is always $\leq H_2(x)$, whereas the above approximation optimizes the choice over the entire domain.

Answer (score 9):

A nice approximation I found in this [thesis](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~ccalabro/thesis.pdf):

$ \frac{x}{2 \log_2 (6/x)} \leq H_2^{-1}(x) \leq \frac{x}{ \log_2 (1/x)}$

Answer (score 3):

A good approximation of $$y=H_2(x) = -x \log_2 (x) - (1-x) \log_2 (1-x)$$ is given by
$$y \sim (4x(1-x))^{3/4}\implies x\sim \frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{1-y^{4/3}}\right)$$ for $0\leq x \leq \frac 12$. This is avery good starting point for Newton method.
$$x_0=\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{1-y^{4/3}}\right)\implies x_1=\frac{\log \left(1+\sqrt{1-y^{4/3}}\right)+(y-1) \log (2)}{2 \tanh
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-y^{4/3}}\right)}$$ which is almost the solution.

**Edit**

*Details about the approximation.*

To match the end points and the maximum, a simple model is
$$H_2 \sim [4x(1-x)]^a$$ Considering the norm
$$\Phi(a)=\int_0^1 \Bigg[-([4x(1-x)]^a-\frac{(1-x) \log (1-x)}{\log (2)}-\frac{x \log (x)}{\log (2)} \Big]^2\,dx$$ we have the analytical expression of $\Phi(a)$. Computing its derivative and solving (numerically), for $a$, $\Phi'(a)=0$ using Newton method, the minimum is attained for $a=0.741967 \sim \frac 34$.

For $a=\frac 34$, $\Phi=0.0000180914$ while at the exact solution    $\Phi=0.0000125374$. Making the root rational $a=\frac{762}{1027}$, we should almost exactly the optimal value of  $\Phi$ (difference $=5.58\times 10^{-16}$).

If instead, we match the value of the second derivative at $x=\frac 12$, $a=\frac{1}{2 \log (2)}=0.721348$.

We can still improve working with the norm related to the inverse function itself.
$$y=[4x(1-x)]^a \implies x_*=\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{1-y^{1/a}}\right)$$
$$\Psi(a)=\int_0^1 \Big[y-H_2(x_*) \Big]^2\,dy$$ is minimum $(\Psi_\text{opt}=0.0000236224)$ when $a=0.746497$ still much closer to the selected $a=\frac 34$.

Using $a=\frac 34$
$$\int_0^1 \Big[y-H_2(x_0) \Big]^2\,dy=2.53 \times 10^{-5}$$
$$\int_0^1 \Big[y-H_2(x_1) \Big]^2\,dy=2.47 \times 10^{-9}$$

Comment: $x_0$ is already an excellent approximation. May I ask what line of reasoning led you to it?

Comment: @pglpm. Details added in the answer.

Comment: Indeed, $x_0$ is an excellent approximation for $p \in (0,1/2]$!  It only starts failing for very small values ( $p< 10^{-5}$)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the remez command in Chebfun (http://www.chebfun.org/) to compute a polynomial that approximates this function very well. Your question is closely connected to approximation theory, and this very user-friendly software should be able to give you anything you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $$k = x \log(x) + (1-x) \log(1-x)$$  where $$k=-H_2(x) \log(2)$$ To stay simple, approximate the rhs by
$$\sum_{n=1}^3 a_n\,\big(x(1-x)\big)^n$$ Minimzing the norm
$$\Phi=\int_0^1 \Bigg(  x \log(x) + (1-x) \log(1-x)-\sum_{n=1}^3 a_n\,\big(x(1-x)\big)^n \Bigg)^2\, dx$$ leads to
$$a_1=-\frac{1297}{280} \qquad \qquad a_2=\frac{451}{35}\qquad  \qquad a_3=-\frac{6149}{280} $$

The real solution of the cubic is
$$x(1-x)=\frac 1 {1677}\Bigg(328-2 \sqrt{\frac{991645}{11}}  \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}(\alpha +\beta \, k)\right)\Bigg)$$ where
$$\alpha=\frac{681970876 }{991645}\sqrt{\frac{11}{991645}}\qquad \qquad \beta=\frac{236235636 }{198329}\sqrt{\frac{11}{991645}}$$

To give an idea of the accuracy, give $x$ a value, compute $k$ and use the formula to recompute $x(1-x)$ and then $x$.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 x & x(1-x) & \text{calculated }x(1-x)& \text{calculated } x\\
 0.05 & 0.04750 & 0.048970 & 0.05164\\
 0.10 & 0.09000 & 0.088793 & 0.09849\\
 0.15 & 0.12750 & 0.125878 & 0.14769\\
 0.20 & 0.16000 & 0.159628 & 0.19938\\
 0.25 & 0.18750 & 0.188474 & 0.25196\\
 0.30 & 0.21000 & 0.211409 & 0.30355\\
 0.35 & 0.22750 & 0.228405 & 0.35305\\
 0.40 & 0.24000 & 0.239969 & 0.39984\\
 0.45 & 0.24750 & 0.246656 & 0.44217\\
 0.50 & 0.25000 & 0.248842 & 0.50000\\
\end{array}
\right)$$