# Find the approximation of the inverse of binary entropy function

Tags: approximation, inverse-function, entropy

I need to find a good approximation for the binary entropy function:

$H_2(x) = -x \log_2(x) -(1-x) \log_2(1-x)$
where x $\in [0,1].$

I tried to find this using matematica and matlab but these tools gives to me an error. Since it seems that this function is not invertible.

Comment: It is of course not invertible, as $h(x) = h(1-x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, I suppose that the function$$h(x) = -x \log_{2}(x) -(1-x) \log_{2}(1-x)\tag1$$  is not invertible.

However, if you are not too concerned by the values close to the boundaries, $h(x)$ can be approximated by a $[4,4]$ Padé approximant built at $x=\frac 12$. This would give
$$h(x) \sim \frac{1- \left(\frac{124}{49}+\frac{2}{\log
   (2)}\right)\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+ \left(\frac{152}{245}+\frac{548}{147 \log
   (2)}\right)\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 } {1-\frac{124}{49} \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{152}{245}
   \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 }\tag2$$ which reduces to a quadratic equation in $\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$.

For sure, this could be improved using the $[6,6]$ Padé approximant which would reduces to a cubic equation in $\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$ which would be less pleasant.

In order to check the quality of the approximation, give $x$ a value in $(1)$ to get $h(x)$ and for this value, solve $(2)$ to get the solution.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x_{\text{given}} & x_{\text{recomputed}} \\
 0.05 &  0.048894 \\
 0.10 &  0.099763 \\
 0.15 &  0.149949 \\
 0.20 &  0.199990 \\
 0.25 &  0.249998 \\
 0.30 &  0.300000 \\
 0.35 &  0.350000 \\
 0.40 &  0.400000 \\
 0.45 &  0.450000 \\
 0.50 &  0.500000 \\
 0.55 &  0.550000 \\
 0.60 &  0.600000 \\
 0.65 &  0.650000 \\
 0.70 &  0.700000 \\
 0.75 &  0.750002 \\
 0.80 &  0.800010 \\
 0.85 &  0.850051 \\
 0.90 &  0.900237 \\
 0.95 &  0.951106
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

The approximation can be improved using again

$$h(x) \sim f(x)=\frac{1+ a\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+ b\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 } {1+c \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+d \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 }$$
In order to respect the boundary conditions, we need to fix $\color{red}{b=-4 (a+4)}$. Now, considering the norm
$$\Phi(a,c,d)=\int_0^1 \big( h(x)-f(x) \big) ^2\,dx $$ its numerical minimization with respect to $a$, $c$ and $d$ (this is equivalent to a nonlinear regression for an infinte number of data points) leads to
$$\{a=-7.14483221448716,\,\, c=-4.28551864360839,\,\,d=2.63456254971723\}$$ At this point $\Phi(a,c,d)=3.44\times 10^{-7}$ while using the Padé approximant the norm would be $3.94\times 10^{-5}$ (that is to say $114$ times larger).

**Update**

If we take the problem for any base $a$,we have
$$h_a(x) = -x \log_{a}(x) -(1-x) \log_{a}(1-x)$$  that is to say
$$h_a(x)\log_e(a)=-x \log_{e}(x) -(1-x) \log_{e}(1-x)$$ and the $[4,4]$ Padé approximant of the rhs is

$$\frac{\log_e(2) + a\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+ b\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^4  }{{1-\frac{124}{49} \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{152}{245}
   \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 } } $$ where
$$a=-\left(2+\frac{124 }{49}\log_e (2)\right)\qquad \text{and} \qquad b=\frac{548}{147}+\frac{152 }{245}\log_e (2)$$ and the norm is equal to $1.89\times 10^{-5}$.

**Update**

Answering this old [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188195/inverse-of-binary-entropy-function-for-0-le-x-le-frac12), I proposed two rather good approximations of the inverse
$$x_0=\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{1-h^{4/3}(x)}\right)$$
$$x_1=\frac{\log \left(1+\sqrt{1-h^{4/3}(x)}\right)+(y-1) \log (2)}{2 \tanh
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-h^{4/3}(x)}\right)}$$

Comment: Hi, thank you a lot for the great answer.
However, since I'm not a mathematician and I'm interested only for a sufficient approximation of the function, in order to find the inverse can I invert directly the equation (2) and get the result ?

Comment: @thinker.92. Yes, for sure. It is just a quadratic equation in  $\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$

Comment: Dear Claude Leibovici, do you know if the approximation that you suggested is valid also for any kind of logarithm base ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @thinker.92. Have a look at my update.

Answer (score 1):

*Four years later, I prefer to add a separate answer.*

$$H_2(x) = -x \log_{2}(x) -(1-x) \log_{2}(1-x)$$

Approximating
$$H_2(x) \sim A \big(x(1-x)\big)^B$$ we should have for the smallest root
$$x_0=\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{1-4
   \left(\frac{H_2(x)}{A}\right)^{\frac{1}{B}}}\right)$$ and the first iterate of Newton method is
$$x_1=\frac{H_2(x) \log (2)+\log (1-x_0)}{2 \tanh ^{-1}(1-2 x_0)}$$

Matching the function and the second derivative values at $x=\frac 12$, the simplest values are
$$A=e \qquad \text{and} \qquad B=\frac{1}{2 \log (2)}$$ However, we can do significantly better minimizing the infinite norm
$$\Phi(A,B)=\int_0^1 \Big(A \big(x(1-x)\big)^B+x \log_{2}(x) +(1-x) \log_{2}(1-x)   \Big)^2\,dx$$ which is analytic.

$A$ is an explicit function of $B$ which is the solution of a quite nasty trancendental equation.

Making the numbers rational
$$A=e+\frac{3029}{29756}\qquad \text{and} \qquad B=\frac{1}{2 \log (2)}+\frac{157}{6379}$$ which reduce the infinite norm by more than $5$ and the maximum error by  a factor of $3$.

Some results

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
H_2(x) & x_0 & x_1 & \text{solution} \\
 0.05 & 0.004511 & 0.005584 &  0.005607 \\
 0.10 & 0.011505 & 0.012966 &  0.012987 \\
 0.15 & 0.019984 & 0.021524 &  0.021540 \\
 0.20 & 0.029681 & 0.031114 &  0.031125 \\
 0.25 & 0.040481 & 0.041687 &  0.041693 \\
 0.30 & 0.052336 & 0.053236 &  0.053239 \\
 0.35 & 0.065238 & 0.065786 &  0.065787 \\
 0.40 & 0.079210 & 0.079383 &  0.079383 \\
 0.45 & 0.094304 & 0.094097 &  0.094097 \\
 0.50 & 0.110600 & 0.110027 &  0.110028 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$