# Why does this approximation for binary entropy of $\cos^ {2}(t)$ hold?

Tags: probability, number-theory, trigonometry, approximation, entropy

I stumbled on an approximation I found surprising while working on a bipartite entanglement entropy problem (which isn't particularly relevant). Alas, I got the following messy result:

$f(x) = -\cos^2(x) \log(\cos^2(x)) -\sin^2(x) \log(\sin^2(x))$

where $\log$ is the natural log measuring entropy in nats. I noticed this function is approximated surprisingly well by:

$h(x) = \log(2) | \sin(2x) |^{2^\gamma}$

where $\gamma \approx 0.5772156649...$ is the Euler–Mascheroni (oily macaroni) constant.

Did a very quick brute force optimization in scipy using mean squared error to roughly estimate the constant, so might not be exact. Overall this seemingly different function does a surprisingly good job ([desmos visual here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mgg8eqdhjx)) at approximating the original complicated one. Also the approximation seems much better at the peaks near log(2) than the troughs near 0. Any insights for why?

[image]

Comment: Obviously $h(x)$ fails to be $C^2$ at precisely the zeros of $\sin 2x$ which is also exactly where $f$ is zero.  So it isn't surprising $h$ is worse around there than around the peak $x=\pi/4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum of the function being at $x=\frac \pi 4$, perform a series expansion to obtain
$$f(x)=\log(2)+-2 \left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^2+\frac{4}{3}
   \left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^4+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi
   }{4}\right)^8\right)$$

Do the same with
$$h(x)=\log(2) \sin^a(2x)$$

$$h(x)=\log (2)-2a\log(2) \left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^2 +\frac{2a
   (3 a-2)}{3} \log(2)  \left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^4 +O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^6\right)$$

Comparing the first coefficient $a=\frac 1 {\log(2)}$

Compare the infinite norms (using the definition of $f(x)$)

$$\Phi_n=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \Big(f(x)-\log(2) \sin^{a_n}(2x)\Big)^2\,dx$$

$$a_1=\frac 1 {\log(2)} \qquad \implies \qquad \Phi_1=6.776\times 10^{-5}$$

$$a_2=2^\gamma \qquad \implies \qquad \Phi_2=1.600\times 10^{-5}$$

Now, using optimization,
$$a_{\text{opt}}=1.49392\qquad \implies \qquad \Phi_{\text{opt}}=1.592\times 10^{-5}$$

For sure, you are the best !

For the fun (thanks to the $ISC$)
$$a_{\text{opt}}\sim \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{5}\right)+J_0(1){}^{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: Ah compelling argument for the exponent as 1/log(2) by matching terms to first order. Although it's a little hard to see, the value of a in the question is actually 2^gamma not 2 * gamma. I get the same values for phi1 and phi2. Considering a3 = 2^gamma, I get a smaller phi3 = 1.599e-05

Comment: Cool! I didn't know about the Inverse Symbolic Calculator, that's really neat! Also, I found your answer approximating classic binary entropy using Padé approximants (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3455391/549436) to be helpful in understanding why the form of $\sin^a(2x)$ shows up. Doing an expansion of that function around the peak at $\frac{1}{2}$ then plugging in $x=\sin^2(t)$ gives the $\sin(2t - \phi)$ form, and the series tweaks the phase and exponent.