# Can we approximate the most likely event's probability if we know the distribution's entropy?

Tags: probability, approximation, information-theory, upper-lower-bounds, entropy

Suppose that we know that a distribution $p$ over small $n$ elements has entropy $H(p)=0.01$. I intentionally chose a small number. Is there some kind of inequality or aproximation to the probability $p_i$ for $i = \arg\max_j p_j$?

What I came up with so far is the following inequality:
$H(p) = \sum _j -p_j \log(p_j) \geq -p_i \log(p_i)$. This gives us in principle an inequality for $p_i$, because if we assume that the most likely event has probability larger than $0.5$ (a consequence of the entropy being sufficiently small for a given $n$), then this inequality $H(p) \geq -p_i \log(p_i)$ should give us a bound on $p_i$ in terms of the entropy. I'm not sure how to solve that inequality for $p_i$ though, or if it's even possible. Maybe an approximation would help as well, that works for small entropy.

**Is there a bound or approximation on the maximum probability $p_i$ in terms of the entropy, that works for sufficiently small entropy?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think one can analytically solve this in terms of elementary functions, but using the monotonicity of $z \mapsto -z \ln z$ for $z > 1/e,$ one can numerically invert your relation to get a lower bound on $p_{i}.$ For small $H$, this should be quite close to $1.$

A slightly better approach is to observe that $$ H(X) = \sum p_j \log \frac{1}{p_j} \ge \sum p_j \log \frac{1}{p_i} = \log \frac{1}{p_i},$$ which immediately tells us that $p_i \ge \exp(-H)$. Note that this improves upon inverting $-p\log p = H$ since $-\log p \ge -p\log p$.

We can in fact do better - let $Y = \mathbf{1}\{X = i\}$. Then the data processing inequality tells us that $H(Y) \le H(X)$. But since $Y$ is a binary function, we can (again numerically, but not analytically) invert the entropy to tell us that $p_{i}$ is either smaller than $h_2^{-1}(H(X))$ or bigger than $1- h_2^{-1}(H(X)),$ where $h_2^{-1}$ is the binary entropy inversion function. If we know that $p_{i} > 1/2,$ then this directly gives a lower bound. For small $H$ this should be the tightest possible lower bound, because the random variable could well be supported on just two letters (or have arbitrarily small mass on all but two), in which case $p_i$ has to step back from $1$ enough to at least give enough binary entropy.

---

Of course, if we're going numerical, then we might as well set up the relevant optimisation program in terms of $H$. Happily, this yields an upper bound upon considering the following convex program \begin{align} p_{\max}(H,n) := &\max p_1 \\ &\textrm{s.t. } \sum_{i = 1}^n  p_i \log p_i = - H, \\ &\phantom{\textrm{s.t. }} \sum_{i = 1}^n p_i = 1,\\ &\phantom{\textrm{s.t. }} \forall i, p_i \ge 0. \end{align}

This has the Lagrangian $$ \mathcal{L} = p_1 + \lambda (\sum p_i \log p_i + H) + \mu(\sum p_i - 1),$$ which yields the first order conditions $$ 1 + \lambda + \lambda \log p_1 + \mu = 0 \\
\forall i \ge 2, \lambda + \lambda \log p_i + \mu = 0,$$ which in turn tells us that the solutions must be of the form $$ (p_1, \pi, \pi, \dots, \pi), \pi = \frac{1-p_1}{n-1},$$ which should make sense - if we want $p_1$ to be big but need to meet an entropy constraint, then the best thing to do is to spread out the remaining mass uniformly on the remainder of the support, to make the relevant conditional entropy as large as possible. In any case, using the above, we may conclude that $p_\max$ must be the largest solution in $[0,1]$ to the equation $$ - p \log p - (1-p) \log \frac{1-p}{n-1} = H \iff h_2(p) + (1-p) \log(n-1) = H.$$

Of course, by definition, we get the upper bound $ p_i \le p_{\max}(H,n).$ I don't quite know how convenient this is, but again, $p_{\max}$ is reasonable to solve for over $[1/2, 1]$ via something like Newton's method or binary search.

As mentioned above, in principle we can also set up a minimisation program (which would minimise $p_1$, but under the extra constraints that $p_1 - p_i \ge 0$ for each $i$), but this should just give the binary entropy inversion solution from above.

Comment: I also wanted to point out that numerically these seem quite good - clearly the bounds will separate as $n$ blows up, and come together as $H$ decreases, but even for the quite large $n = 10^8$ and the modest $H = 0.1$ (in nats), I get the bounds (via Wolfram alpha) $0.979 \le p_i \le 0.996.$ For comparison, $\exp(-0.1) \approx 0.905,$ while the inversion of $-p_i \log p_i = 0.1$ is roughly $0.894$.

Comment: Upon re-reading, this is a bit stream of consciousness. More briefly:  note that we can express the entropy as $H = h_2(p_i) + (1-p_i)H(X|Y = 0),$ for $Y = \mathbf{1}\{X = i\}$. So, $h_2(p_i) \le H \le h_2(p_i) + (1-p_i)\log(n-1) =: g(p_i)$. Now, given $H,n$, $p_i$ must satisfy these relations. If $H \le 1\textrm{ bit},$ then we know that $p_i \ge 1/2$. Both $h_2(p)$ and $g(p)$ are decreasing on $[1/2, 1]$. Thus, the solutions to the equations $h_2(p) = H$ and $g(p) = H$ on $[1/2,1]$ respectively give (tight) lower and upper bounds for $p_i$, and can be found by binary search.

Comment: I like the lower bound $p^*\geq e^{-H}$, which btw also gives $p^*\geq 1-H$. I would love to have a similarly simple upper bound, if it exists. The numerical bounds aren't so useful to me (though I know I didn't say that explicitly in the question). Should I ask for a closed form upper bound in a different question?

Comment: @user56834 I guess so? Equivalently you're asking for elementary upper and lower bounds to the solutions of the two equations that I'm proposing to solve numerically, which does seem like it could be a nice question (that I don't know a good attack for :) ). It's probably worth putting a concrete motivation into it too, which would really help clarify what kind of answer you'd be happy with (e.g. maybe you're looking for some nice bounds that plug into some analysis. Then describing the form of the equations would give a sense of what kind of functions are useful etc).

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $$H(X) = h(p_j) + (1-p_j) H(X \backslash x_j)  \tag 1$$

where $h$ is binary entropy function and $H(X \backslash x_j)$ is the entropy of the remaining values (or equivalenty, $H(X \mid X \ne x_j)$  ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4271669/312)).

This gives a lower and upper bound of the entropy in terms of $p_j$:

$$ h(p_j) \le H(X) \le  h(p_j) + (1 - p_j) \log(n-1) \tag 2 $$

where $n=|{\cal X}|$ is the cardinality of the variable $X$ support. (Of course, the logarithm should be in base $2$ if the entropy is expressed in bits).

[image]

The graph displays this lower bound  (eq $(2)$, in green) and the upper bound for $n=3$ (blue) and $n=9$ (red), for $p_j \to 1$.  The entropy, in the vertical axis, in bits.

The permisible pairs $(H, p_j)$ lie between the green and red/blue lines.
Hence $(2)$ give lower and upper bounds for $p_j$, which should be computed numerically. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188195/inverse-of-binary-entropy-function-for-0-le-x-le-frac12).

A semiempirical approximation for the lower bound, for the range $0.01 \le H < 0.4$ :
$$ p_j \approx 1- \frac{a H}{b - \log(H)}$$

where  $a=0.73$, $b = 2.3$.

Comment: Is this a lower or upper bound on the max probability?

Comment: It's an upper bound. I clarified and added the lower bound.

Comment: but this is an upper and lower bound on the entropy. I am assuming that we already know the entropy, and we want a bound on the maximum probability (preferably lower and upper). Also, the equation you gave seems hard to invert for $p^{max}$ btw.

Comment: @user56834 Eq $(2)$ gives a bounds for $H$ in terms of $p_j$, but (as the graph shows) it translates into bounds for $p_j$ in terms of $H$, only that there is not a a closed form formula. It should be evaluated numerically or by approximations. In the final paragraph I give such an approximation.

Comment: I don't like the fact that these bounds aren't closed form, though I know that I didn't explicitly ask for that in the question. Is it possible to formulate (weaker) closed form lower and upper bounds for the maximum probability $p^*$ based on this?

Comment: > I don't like the fact that these bounds aren't closed form
Well, try to overcome that dislike. "Closed form" is a fuzzy term (and probably less important than you think). $sin(x)=y$ has no "closed form" solution for $x$ until you invent the arcsin function. Same for $x^x=y$ until you invent the Lambert-W function. And so on.

Comment: the reaaon I want it to be closed form is so that I can very eaaily calculate a rough upper bound immediately in my head. $p\geq 1-H$ is very good for this purpose

Comment: I have already given an approximate explicit "closed form" bound in the last paragraph