# For a probability distribution is the difference between the largest and smallest probabilities bounded by the Shannon entropy?

Tags: probability, inequality, information-theory, entropy

Consider a set of probabilities $\{p_1, ..., p_N\}$ where $p_1\leq p_2\leq ... \leq p_N$. Now consider the difference between the largest and smallest probabilities $D =p_N-p_1$. I want to know if one can use the Shannon entropy of the distribution to find a bound on $D$. The Shannon entropy is given by $H = -\sum_i p_i \log p_i$.

Some properties of $D$:

- $0\leq D\leq1$
- $D$ is minimized (ie. $D=0$) for a uniform distribution where $p_i = \frac{1}{N}$. This is the maximum entropy distribution.
- D is maximized (ie. $D=1$) for a distribution where $p_N=1$ and $p_i=0$ for $i\neq N$. This is the minimum entropy distribution.

Clearly, $D$ is not simply bounded by $H$, since $0\leq D\leq1$ and $0\leq H\leq \log(N)$. But they do seem to be related.

My question is: can we say anything about intermediate entropy distributions? Given the entropy of a distribution, can one find an upper (or lower) bound for $D$?

Comment: Are you looking for analytical or numerical bounds? I think you can set up a program for $D$ as in the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4404974/can-we-approximate-the-most-likely-events-probability-if-we-know-the-distributi/4405016#4405016), and probably solve it in $N^2$ time. Analytical bounds will probably be looser.

Comment: I was ideally looking for analytical bounds (don't mind too much if they're loose). But thanks for the numerical answer.

Comment: We assume that $H$ and also $N$ are given, right?

Comment: Yes, assume $H$ and $N$ are given.