# Solving Logarithmic Expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, physics, problem-solving, chemistry

In the context of the thermodynamics of mixing two separate gases at the same temperature and pressure, one has the generic equation,
\begin{gather*}
-\frac{\Delta S_{mix}}{nR} = X_A \ln(X_A) + X_B \ln(X_B)
\end{gather*}
where $S$ is the entropy, $n$ is the moles, $R$ is the ideal gas constant, and $X_A$ refers to the mole fraction of a substance $A$ in the mixture. If we are given $\Delta S_{mix}$ along with the total moles of gas, and if we exploit the fact that the two mole fractions should add to 100% ($X_B = 1-X_A$), this amounts to solving a difficult logarithmic equation of the form,
\begin{align*}
C &= x \ln(x) + (1-x) \ln(1-x) \\
&=\ln(1-x) + x\ln \left( \frac{x}{1-x} \right)
\end{align*}
where $C$ is just a constant for convenience. After trying several different manipulations with the rules for logarithms, I just ended up with what seems like a more intractable mess. Is there a way to actually solve this algebraically for $x$, or is there absolutely no hope here?

Comment: I added a quite decent closed form approximation.

Comment: I had a look to your profile. Just for your curiosity, I was the last student working under the NP  in Physics (1929)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start using$$x \log(x) + (1-x) \log(1-x)=-\log(2)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{2^{2 n-1}}{n (2 n-1)}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2 n}$$

To give an idea of the quality of the approximation, consider the partial sum
$$S_p=-\log(2)+\sum_{n=1}^p  \frac{2^{2 n-1}}{n (2 n-1)}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2 n}$$

and the corresponding infinite norm
$$\Phi_p=\int_0^1\Big(x \log(x) + (1-x) \log(1-x)-S_p   \Big)^2\, dx$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & \Phi_p \\
 1 & 2.38986\times 10^{-3} \\
 2 & 4.79841\times 10^{-4} \\
 3 & 1.68129\times 10^{-4} \\
 4 & 7.72283\times 10^{-5} \\
 5 & 4.16231\times 10^{-5} \\
 6 & 2.49278\times 10^{-5} \\
 7 & 1.60876\times 10^{-5} \\
 8 & 1.09776\times 10^{-5} \\
 9 & 7.82106\times 10^{-6} \\
 10 & 5.76722\times 10^{-6} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Truncate the series to some order and use power series reversion.

This would give
$$\color{blue}{x=\frac 12 +t-\frac{t^3}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\,t^{2n}}\qquad \text{where} \qquad \color{blue}{t=\sqrt{\frac{C+\log (2)}{2} }}$$ where the first coefficients are
$$\left\{1,\frac{13}{30},\frac{97}{210},\frac{25307}{37800},\frac{5
   6827}{49896},\frac{1457147323}{681080400},\frac{14645196257}{3
   405402000},\cdots\right\}$$

**Edit**

For $0\leq x \leq \frac 12$, I already wrote (have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188195/inverse-of-binary-entropy-function-for-0-le-x-le-frac12)) that we can make a good approximation

$$x \log(x) + (1-x) \log(1-x) \sim -\log(2) \big(4 x (1-x) \big)^{3/4}$$
So, the first estimate is
$$\color{blue}{x_0=\frac 12(1-t)}\qquad\text{where}\qquad \color{blue}{t=\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{|C|}{\log (2)}\right)^{4/3}}} $$ is a decent approximation of te solution.

To improve it, use the first iterate of Newton method
$$x_1=x_0-\frac {f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}$$ where
$$f(x)=x \log(x) + (1-x) \log(1-x)-C$$
$$f'(x)=\log (x)-\log (1-x)$$

$$\large\color{blue}{x_1=\frac {\log(1+t)  -(C+\log(2)) } {2 \tanh ^{-1}(t) }}$$

Some numbers

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
c & x_0 & x_1 & \text{solution} \\
 -0.05 & 0.007564 & 0.008696 &  0.008713 \\
 -0.10 & 0.019289 & 0.020496 &  0.020506 \\
 -0.15 & 0.033611 & 0.034481 &  0.034484 \\
 -0.20 & 0.050185 & 0.050505 &  0.050505 \\
 -0.25 & 0.068936 & 0.068599 &  0.068599 \\
 -0.30 & 0.089935 & 0.088903 &  0.088906 \\
 -0.35 & 0.113377 & 0.111666 &  0.111674 \\
 -0.40 & 0.139600 & 0.137270 &  0.137283 \\
 -0.45 & 0.169147 & 0.166300 &  0.166318 \\
 -0.50 & 0.202903 & 0.199687 &  0.199710 \\
 -0.55 & 0.242414 & 0.239038 &  0.239065 \\
 -0.60 & 0.290813 & 0.287584 &  0.287612 \\
 -0.65 & 0.356713 & 0.354163 &  0.354187 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

For sure, the first estimate of Halley or Householder methods (still closed form formulae) wold be better. No problem to write them.

Comment: I appreciate this detailed answer. I surmise from the numerical approximation techniques used here that there is no conceivable way to find a closed-form solution? This is really sad, as I was hoping to write a cool homework problem with this idea.

Comment: @MattHanson. No way to get a closed form. By the way, you made me younger since I made this 57 years ago.

Comment: That’s a bummer. It seems like the sort of problem in thermodynamics that “should be solvable,” but alas that’s how it goes. Thanks for giving a good approximation technique!

Comment: @MattHanson. Among other activities, I have been much involved in equations of state for gases.

Comment: That’s great! I’m definitely more focused on quantum, so I’m sure my students would have rather had you for thermo, ha.?

Comment: @MattHanson. Most of my work have been in quantum chemistry (M.O) for ground ans excited states. I suppose that I have almost hundred papers in this area.